# In class $2$ nilpotent groups, does $[G:HZ]<\infty$ imply $[G:H]<\infty$?

Tags: group-theory, nilpotence, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a finitely generated nilpotent group of class $2$. Denote the center of $G$ by $Z$. Let $H\leq G$ be a subgroup such that $[G:HZ]<\infty$. Does it follow that $[G:H]<\infty$.

Equivalently, since $[G:H]=[G:HZ]\cdot[HZ:H]=[G:HZ]\cdot[Z:H\cap Z]$, does it follow that $[Z:H\cap Z]<\infty$?

Comment: No it doesn't follow. $H$ could be a direct factor of $G$, with the other factor infinite abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks. If I replace $Z$ by $[G,G]$, the statement does become true, right?

Comment: Yes, the statement becomes true if you replace $Z$ by $D =[G,G]$, basically because $D \le Z$ so $[HD,HD] = [H,H]$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Isn't the statement for $[G,G]$ true for nilpotent groups of all classes, irregardless of whether $[G,G]\leq Z$?

Comment: Yes I believe it is!